# How did the Non Bani Israel became the followers of Prophet Moses

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, moshe-rabbeinu

What does the Tanach say on How non bani israelites embraced the religion of Prophet Moses at the time of Prophet Moses.

Comment: the discussions of methodology ( https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:FFWrOIGA1GUJ:www.parshailluminations.com/convert.pdf+&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgovyOz6M6LuBHHasyY2WZNdqqYF6WS_Wj_eXXXiM6WCtD60o5wuLXNjdKdWcb48fH55BwpEzmdL2eoZ5RKW6eCiYAsOhdUNYJuHSYHcP5kRTypg65QTObAfJdp8JORtw6qROiv&sig=AHIEtbQ4KvvfgqV_BKxKM-f7ElEe7hwi7A ) mention "join" as an action marked simply by association and "convert" (though usually insincerely) which might have required at least circumcision, but that process is not detailed.

Comment: Are you asking about the erev rav, the non-Israelites who came along from Egypt and joined the people, or about somebody after that?  Aside from them, Yitro, and perhaps Moshe's wife (depending on how you count that), I'm not sure the Tanakh records anybody joining the Jewish people during Moshe's lifetime.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26963/who-is-a-jew-according-the-tanach#comment62500_26963

Answer (score 3):

The TaNa"Ch is not at all clear on this subject.

There are examples, however, of non-Israelites who joined Bnei Yisrael (ie., converted) in the times of Moshe, including the 'Erev Rav and Moshe's own father-in-law Yithro, as well as Moshe's wife Tzipporah, for that matter, but there is no real prescriptive approach to converting given.  On the other hand, Yithro is a subject of dispute as to [whether and when he converted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14198/5).